# Saving Data that's Been Run Through ActivePerl

Tags: perl

This must be a basic question, but I can't find a satisfactory answer to it. I have a script here that is meant to convert CSV formatted data to TSV. I've never used Perl before now and I need to know how to save the data that is printed after the Perl script runs it though.

Script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $filename = data.csv;
open FILE, $filename or die "can't open $filename: $!";
while (<FILE>) {
s/"//g;
s/,/\t/g;
s/Begin\.Time\.\.s\./Begin Time (s)/;
s/End\.Time\.\.s\./End Time (s)/;
s/Low\.Freq\.\.Hz\./Low Freq (Hz)/;
s/High\.Freq\.\.Hz\./High Freq (Hz)/;
s/Begin\.File/Begin File/;
s/File\.Offset\.\.s\./File Offset (s)/;
s/Random.Number/Random Number/;
s/Random.Percent/Random Percent/;
print;
}
```

All the data that's been analyzed is in the cmd prompt. How do I save this data?

edit: 
**thank you everyone! It worked perfectly!**

Comment: How sure are you that the fields in your original file contain no embedded commas? Your `s/,/\t/g` is going to do nasty things to those.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but my original data file is a csv, which has embedded commas. I basically needed to get rid of the commas and replace them with tabs so my program can read the data properly.

Comment: My point is that not all commas in a CSV file are the field separators. Some can appear within the fields - and your code doesn't handle those correctly. I'll write an answer to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your cmd prompt:

```
perl yourscript.pl > C:\result.txt
```

Here you run the perl script and redirect the output to a file called result.txt

Answer (score 0):

It's always potentially dangerous to treat all commas in a CSV file as field separators. CSV files can also include commas embedded within the data. Here's an example.

```
1,"Some data","Some more data"
2,"Another record","A field with, an embedded comma"
```

In your code, the line `s/,/\t/g` treats all tabs the same and the embedded comma in the final field will also be expanded to a tab. That's probably not what you want.

Here's some code that uses Text::ParseWords to do this correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::ParseWords;

while (<>) {
  my @line = parse_line(',', 0, $_);
  $_ = join "\t", @line;

  # All your s/.../.../ lines here

  print;
}
```

If you run this, you'll see that the comma in the final field doesn't get updated.